# State is not defined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, error-handling

I'm new to react and I'm getting an error for the state and method:

> ./src/App.js
> Line 5:  'state' is not defined               no-undef
> Line 8:  'inputchangehandler' is not defined  no-undef

This is my code until now:

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';

function App() {
state = {
  userInput: ''
}
 inputchangehandler = (event) => {
    this.setState = ({
      userInput: event.target.value
    })
  }
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <input type="text" name="name" 
      onChange={this.inputchangehandler} 
      value = {this.state.userInput}/>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

In react there are 2 types of components.

1. Functional Components(like you used)
2. Class Components

Functional Components are stateless(in older versions, you can use `hooks` now) components. So if you want to directly use `state` you should change your components to class based component like this:

```
import React, { Component} from 'react';
import './App.css';

class App extends Component {
state = {
  userInput: ''
}
 inputchangehandler = (event) => {
    this.setState = ({
      userInput: event.target.value
    })
  }
render(){
return (
        <div className="App">
          <input type="text" name="name" 
          onChange={this.inputchangehandler} 
          value = {this.state.userInput}/>
        </div>
      );
    }
}


export default App;
```

Comment: If you refactor a Class component to a Functional Component (using hooks such as useState) and you forget to change property from **state.myProperty** to **myProperty** you will also get "state is not defined" error.

Answer (score 4):

Functional component don't have state, form React 16.8 we have `Hooks`.

You should use [`useState`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html) hook for state.

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';


const [userInput, setUserInput] = useState('')
```

Usage,

```
<input type="text" name="name" 
      onChange={inputchangehandler} 
      value = {userInput}/>
```

`inputchangehandler` function should be,

```
const inputchangehandler = (event) => {
    setUserInput(event.target.value)
}
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ugtr3b)

**Note:** Functional component don't have access to `this`.

Answer (score 1):

You have created functional component which does not have state. Define `App` as class component like below :

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';

class App extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            userInput: ''
        }
    }

    inputchangehandler = (event) => {
        this.setState = ({
            userInput: event.target.value
        })
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="App">
                <input type="text" name="name"
                    onChange={this.inputchangehandler}
                    value={this.state.userInput} />
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to define state in your class's constructor like below:

```js
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        userInput: ''
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Declaring your component as a function you don't have state.
Try converting it in class component or in a function using Hooks according to [react documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html).

Answer (score 0):

If you are using React version greater than 16.8 then you can use the `useState` hook.

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';


function App() {
const [userInput, setUserInput] = useState(0);

 inputchangehandler = (event) => {
    setUserInput(event.target.value)
  }
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <input type="text" name="name" 
      onChange={this.inputchangehandler} 
      value = {userInput}/>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Refer: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html

If you are using an older version then you will need to convert it to a `React.Component`

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to write a class component, you should use hooks, so your code will be like this:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import './App.css';

function App() {

const [userInput, setUserInput] = useState(undefined);


 inputchangehandler = (event) => {
    setUserInput(event.target.value)
 }
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <input type="text" name="name" 
      onChange={this.inputchangehandler} 
      value = {userInput}/>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

i was on React version 17 this worked for me for state undefined error:
Adding example from React official docs:

```
class Clock extends React.Component {   constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {date: new Date()};   }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Hello, world!</h1>
        <h2>It is {this.state.date.toLocaleTimeString()}.</h2>
      </div>
    );   } }
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're working with a class component rather than a functional component (as mentioned in other answers), the error `state is not defined` can occur if you forgot to prefix it with `this.`.

Instead of:

```
myFunction() {
  let myVariable = state.myStateKey;
  // ...
}
```

Do:

```
myFunction() {
  let myVariable = this.state.myStateKey;
  // ...
}
```